# Designing an IOS settings page

Tags: ios, applications

This is probably obvious, but I haven't found my answer yet. When designing for ios, do I absolutely have to use their "settings page" design or can I make my own? This is my first go at designing for ios and I have a lot to learn.

Comment: What do you mean, "use their settings page"? What are you creating?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Apple's settings page–the standard one. I need to make an account settings page, but don't know if I can create my own or if I have to use what I've normally seen on iPhone. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not exactly. Is the account settings just for your application? In that case then you can create like you would any other page of your application. If you're talking about adding to the original iOS settings, I don't think you can do do that directly

Comment: So doing something like this is ok? http://imgur.com/UYW0SFT       @Zach Saucier

Comment: I would think so

Comment: Ok, great! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something against iOS rules. @Zach Saucier

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own settings page or use the native settings app. [Apple's suggested method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW3) is dependent on the use of the settings: Frequently changed preferences should use a custom UI. Infrequently changed preferences should use a Settings bundle (the native settings app).

[From the iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html):

> Apps then have two options for presenting preferences:
>
> - Display preferences inside the app.
> - Use a Settings bundle to manage preferences from the Settings app.
>
> Which option you choose depends on how you expect users to interact with preferences. The Settings bundle is generally the preferred mechanism for displaying preferences. However, games and other apps that contain configuration options or other frequently accessed preferences might want to present them inside the app instead.

If you do implement your own settings interface, there is no standard or guideline to how you display those settings:

> There is no standard way to display custom preferences from inside an iOS app. You can integrate preferences in many ways, including using a separate tab in a tab-bar interface or using a custom button from one of your app’s screens. Preferences should generally be presented using a distinct view controller so that changes in preferences can be recorded when that view controller is dismissed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it just depends on you and your relation with your team. 
When creating a new app design, you have at least 2 choices:

1. if you want to make it fast, you use the default UI library of the OS (it takes less time to create components, but you're limited when it comes to creativity)
2. if you are not constrained by a tight deadline, you can create your custom UI, but following the best practices and guidelines defined by the OS provider (it takes longer to create components, but you have little constrains when it comes to creativity).

So, to answer your question, Crystal, YES, you can create custom pages, which may be implemented in an app which uses standard UI components, whenever you want (as long as the developers are not angry about it xD). You are not constrained about certain design guidelines at all.